# Desactivar refresco de pagina en móvil al arrastrar el dedo hacia abajo (No F5)

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una web que la abren en un teléfono, el problema que tengo es que por alguna razón, actualizan la pagina bajando el dedo por la pantalla del teléfono y me gustaría poder evitar esto.
He intentado con esto:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return false;
};
```

Pero el navegador me lanza un mensaje diciendo que se pueden perder los datos que si estoy seguro . La idea es que no haga nada.

Comment: Ese es el comportamiento normal del navegador del móvil y, en caso de que funcione `onbeforeunload`, no vas a permitir que los usuarios salgan de tu página. Es muy molesto y, si son como yo, nunca van a regresar.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, Es una html que deben de usar ya que es su trabajo, le puse un botón de cerrar sessión pero cuando le dan a actualizar se sale de la pagina en la que están actualmente. Es lo que no quiero.

Comment: `onbeforeunload` no hace que se cancele el evento, a menos que el usuario así lo elija en la ventana que aparece. Afortunadamente, los navegadores no permiten cambiar ese comportamiento. En todo caso, debes revisar tu proyecto para ver de qué forma hacer que se mantenga en la misma página al recargar.

Comment: ¿De veras el sitio se actualiza al arrastrar la página hacia abajo sin que hayas capturado y configurado un evento? Por defecto no debería ocurrir, yo tengo un iPhone y eso nunca sucede.

Comment: @ArielMontes Si estás en el top de la página actual e intentas "ir hacia arriba", el navegador Chrome lo interpreta de igual modo que pulsar Ctrl + R en un PC (recarga la página)

Comment: Entonces es una cosa ligada al navegador Chrome. No había entendido esa parte.